Manipulator/Manipulate "StepRightButton" freezes below 0.5 step size
I noticed in version 14.1 on Win 11 that the behavior of the "StepRightButton" in Manipulator and Manipulate freezes for step values below 0.5. It may take 1 or more clicks before it freezes. Has anyone else noticed this or can you reproduce? Here are a few examples:

Step value 0.5 works as expected

With[{step = 0.5},
 {{Manipulator[Dynamic[x], {150, 170, step}, Appearance -> "Open", 
    AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "StepLeftButton", 
      "StepRightButton"}], Dynamic[x]}, 
  Manipulate[x, {x, 150, 170, step, Appearance -> "Open"}, 
   AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "StepLeftButton", 
     "StepRightButton"}]}
 ]


Step value 0.4 freezes after 1 or more clicks

With[{step = 0.4},
 {{Manipulator[Dynamic[x], {150, 170, step}, Appearance -> "Open", 
    AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "StepLeftButton", 
      "StepRightButton"}], Dynamic[x]}, 
  Manipulate[x, {x, 150, 170, step, Appearance -> "Open"}, 
   AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "StepLeftButton", 
     "StepRightButton"}]}
 ]

I've submitted a report to WRI.
